# How to store the value of a button press?

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

For example I want to store the value of a button press into a variable, so I can have a single proc for all three buttons and perform operations specific to each variable value without code duplication.

```
button .buttonRed -text "Red" -command "popUpColor"
button .buttonBlue -text "Blue" -command "popUpColor" 
button .buttonGreen -text "green" -command "popUpColor"
```

Answer (score 1):

Let your handler command take a parameter:

```
button .buttonRed -text "Red" -command "popUpColor red"
button .buttonBlue -text "Blue" -command "popUpColor blue" 
button .buttonGreen -text "green" -command "popUpColor green"

proc popUpColor color {
    ...
}
```

---

Note that quotes aren't syntax for strings, they are just for grouping (and some quoting: e.g.  and `;` are just text characters inside double quotes). So this

```
button .buttonRed -text "Red" -command "popUpColor red"
```

is exactly equal to this

```
button .buttonRed -text Red -command "popUpColor red"
```

You can use this to simplify the code a bit:

```
foreach color {Red Blue Green} {
    button .button$color -text $color -command "popUpColor $color"
}
```

But note that constructing the value of the `-command` option as a simple string can be problematic if a list value is interpolated. For example,

```
... -command "foo $bar"
```

will be ok if `$bar` is, say, `123`, but if it is `{1 2 3}`, then the command option value will be `foo 1 2 3`.

For this reason it is a good idea to always construct invocation values as lists:

```
... -command [list foo $bar]
```

becomes `foo {1 2 3}`.

So you should use

```
button .buttonRed -text "Red" -command [list popUpColor red]
...
```

or

```
foreach color {Red Blue Green} {
    button .button$color -text $color -command [list popUpColor $color]
}
```

even though it makes no difference in this example.

Comment: Build the command with `list`. Stops tricky bits from cropping up when complicated strings are passed across.

Answer (score 0):

Found an alternative way:

```
button .buttonRed -text "Red" -command "popUpColor .buttonRed"
button .buttonBlue -text "Blue" -command "popUpColor .buttonBlue" 
button .buttonGreen -text "green" -command "popUpColor .buttonGreen"

proc whatcolor { color } {
#some code here
}
```

Comment: Note that hardcoding widget paths in your command scripts will make it harder to maintain your code. If you pass the color name instead, it is more likely that your changed code can still use that.

Answer (score 0):

Adding parameters to the command string, as the answers have pointed out, is the way to get the result you're asking for, but you might want to consider using a radiobutton instead. It's a better control if you only want to have one option available out of several, and it has a -textvariable option to store the result in a variable without having to write a helper function.